# GET 404 error for css and js files

Tags: html

I am trying to use an HTML5 template with my code using node.js for my home page, but I keep getting a GET 404 Not Found error for: main.css, jquery.min.js, skel.min.js, and main.js. I checked my directory, and everything seems to be in the right place. Below is a snapshot of it:

[image: Snapshot of directory]

And here is the HTML where I linked my css and js files in the index.html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error and what I can do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a beginning slash to your `src` and `href` attributes.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work-- now I get this error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for the four files.

Comment: Try adding '../path_to_file'. specifically the '../'

Comment: Still no luck; I get the GET 404 error like the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've specified your static asset directory. (http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/serving-static-files-in-nodejs)

Aside from that:

Try setting your script paths to include the precursory slash:

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="/assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

If that isn't working, and you're running Adblock in your browser, try disabling it.

Check to see if you're able to see the files if you paste the address into the browser?